# SegFault when iterating through LinkedList

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm new to C programming and I tried to create a SingleLinkedList. I've ran into a problem when iterating through the List, but I got no clue why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node {
    int val;
};

struct entry {
    struct entry *next;
    struct node node;
};

struct list_head {
    struct entry *next;
};


/* Insert new element in the beginning of the list */
void list_add(struct list_head *list, struct entry *new)
{
    if(list == NULL)
    {
        printf("%s", "Please make sure your head isn't NULL!");

        return;
    }
    else
    {
        new->next = list->next;
        list->next = new;
    }
}


/* Check, whether entry is the last entry of the list */
bool list_is_last(struct entry *entry)
{
    if(entry->next == NULL)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

void print_list(struct list_head *list)
{
    if(list == NULL)
    {
        printf("%s", "Please make sure your head isn't NULL!");

        return;
    }

    if(list->next != NULL)
    {
        struct entry* current;

        current = list->next;

        while(!list_is_last(current))
        {
            printf("%i \n", current->node.val);

            current = current->next;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct list_head* head;
    head = malloc(sizeof(struct list_head));
    head->next == NULL;

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        struct entry* e = malloc(sizeof(struct entry));

        e->node.val = i + 1;
        e->next = NULL;

        list_add(head, e);
    }

    print_list(head);

    return 0;
}
```

I always get a SegmentationFault at the list_is_last method when accessing the last item of the list. I don't actually get why, because in my opinion he should not enter the while-Loop in the "last" iteration, because the pointer "next" of the last variable should be NULL.

I'd be glad if someone can help me.

Comment: `struct node node`. Variable naming could have been better!

Comment: Put `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: `head->next == NULL;` --> `head->next = NULL;`

Comment: Also The value of the last node is not printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The boolean last node check should be (This is what would let you print the last node of the list).

```
    if( entry == NULL )
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
```

Also you should assign the value of head->next to null.
`head->next=NULL`

---

#### Few must have in your code:

- **Don't forget to `free` what you have allocated.**
- You should check the return value of `malloc`. For example:-

  struct list_head* head;
  head = malloc(sizeof(struct list_head));
  if(head == NULL){
     fprintf(stderr,"%s","Error in malloc");
     exit(1);
  }
- You should include `stdlib.h` to run this code. (`malloc` etc).

---

#### Good to Have:-

Also there are few things you can do to make your code more readable:-

- Select proper variable names. It helps you maintain the code in long run.
- Try compiling the code and look for the possible error and warning messages.
- Also dry run your code at times to get small bug in your code.

#### Most inportant question "Why did the segfault occur?"?

The reason is you were first of all assigning the `head-next == NULL`. This is basically just an comparison, the value of `head->next` doesn't change.

`head->next` contained garbage value.

Now you were thinking  that you have assigned it to `NULL` but no you have used `==` instead of `=`.

Now if you think from the logic of node insertion in the linked list you will see that you are adding the nodes with value `1,2,3,4...10` in the list head.

So list becomes after inserting everything `10->9->..._.2->1->(X)`.

You thought (X) = NULL but actually it is garbage value.

Now you started to print it.

You are doing fine and then you went to the last node `1`. Then you checked if `next` of this is `NULL` and which is certainly not the case so you printed `1` and then you made current `NULL` now you are dereferencing some garbage value...from this point onwards it's Undefined behavior. And your program may print a garbage value and blowup or simply blow up.

That's what happened.

Also why it is needed to change the logic to `entry==NULL` ...you will understand that if you draw an image in paper and think. I will leave it as an assignment.

Comment: I guess I did something wrong..waiting to learn where I did the mistake.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't see that I had a == instead of a =. I'm sorry.

Comment: To the downvoter I don't mind if I get a downvote ..I just want to improve the answer. Thanks that you read my answer.